# How to find percentile of exponential distribution with ti-84

Tags: probability, statistics, calculator

Hello I am taking an online statistics class as part of a nursing program that I am in and we are using a free online textbook from lumenlearning. I am currently learning about uniform and exponential distributions and understand everything so far but on the exponential distributions I am having a lot of trouble with how to find a percentile, please look at the exact resource I am using here, I am specifically on the third box down on the page:
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/the-exponential-distribution/
I am seeing how they got these probabilities easily with my TI-84 Plus but once they start with trying to find the 50th percentile of this exponential distribution where the mean is the amount of time spent with a customer, and the average amount of time spent with each customer is four minutes. This is what they have for how they found the probability:

> $P(x < k) = 0.50$, $k = 2.8$ minutes (calculator or computer)
>
> Half of all customers are finished within $2.8$ minutes.
>
> You can also do the calculation as follows:
>
> $P(x < k) = 0.50$ and $P(x < k) = 1 – e^{–0.25k}$
>
> Therefore, $0.50 = 1 − e^{−0.25k}$ and $e^{−0.25k} = 1 − 0.50 = 0.5$
>
> Take natural logs: $ln(e^{–0.25k}) = ln(0.50)$. So, $–0.25k = ln(0.50)$
>
> Solve for $k$:   $k=\frac{\ln(0.50)}{−0.25}=0.25=2.8$ minutes

And I am not understanding that at all, what exactly is the formula for finding the percentile and what should I be entering in my calculator? I see that if I enter $LN(0.5)/-0.25$ I get $2.77$ which rounds up to $2.8$, but I don't understand how they got there? Also the next box down has a very similar problem where they want you to find the 50th percentile with an average time of 15 days in an exponential distribution, but I am not seeing how they are getting an answer of $10.4$ days for that one?

Any help is very much appreciated I have not taken any math classes for several years so am having to look up what a lot of these things mean but when it comes to this I am just clueless. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments interjected below.

> You can also do the calculation as follows:
>
> $P(x < k) = 0.50$ and $P(x < k) = 1 – e^{–0.25k}$

The left equation is what we want; we're hunting for a value $k$ that marks the median of the distribution -- i.e. a we want the $x$-coordinate where half the distribution lies to its left and the other half to its right.

The right equation uses the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of $X$, which they mention, but don't seem to prove, up above:

> $\color{blue}{\text{The cumulative distribution function (CDF) gives the area to the left.}}$
>
> $\color{blue}{P(X < x) = 1 – e^{–mx}}$

On that linked page, this fact sort of just seems to appear, but it's completely crucial to everything that follows. If you actually wanted to show *why* that's true, you'd need calculus (which I'm guessing you're not familiar with). But this CDF is exactly what we need; it's a function that takes in an input ($x$) and outputs the probability of being at or below $x$. In other words, we are hunting for exactly the place where that CDF reaches the height of $0.5$.

> Therefore, $0.50 = 1 − e^{−0.25k}$

Here, they've just written down an equation summarizing my previous comment.

> and $e^{−0.25k} = 1 − 0.50 = 0.5$

On this step, they just did some algebra; namely, they subtracted $e^{-0.25k}$ and $0.5$ from each side, then simplified. Now, they're trying to solve for $k$, but it's locked up in the exponent of something, so they'll need a way to knock it down. The best tool to do this is the natural log $(\ln)$, because this function is defined as the inverse of $e^x$, so it cancels $e$ when it is found as a base of other stuff. That is, $\ln(e^x) = x$, so $\ln(e^{\text{whatever}}) = \text{whatever}$.

> Take natural logs: $ln(e^{–0.25k}) = ln(0.50)$.

They just took a natural log of both sides of the equation; remember that you can do *whatever you want* to both sides of an equation so long as you do the same thing to both sides. Next, they'll use that cancellation property I mentioned:

> So, $–0.25k = ln(0.50)$

Finally, they divide both sides by $-0.25$.

> Solve for $k$:   $k=\frac{\ln(0.50)}{−0.25}=0.25=2.8$ minutes

The steps for the other problem are the same; the crux is to solve the equation $0.5 = 1 - e^{-1/15 x}$, where we use $-1/15$ in the exponent because it's the reciprocal of the mean, as they describe in the first example box.

Comment: Thank you so so soooo much! this really helped me a ton!